# How can I extract Flatten Layer Output for each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, flatten, conv-neural-network

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(50, (5,5), activation='relu', input_shape =(5,5,1), kernel_initializer='he_normal'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

# compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_checkpoint=ModelCheckpoint(r'C:\Users\globo\Desktop\Test_CNN\Results\Kernel5x5\Weights'+'\\'+test+'\model_test{epoch:02d}.h5',save_freq=1,save_weights_only=True)

# fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=1, callbacks=[model_checkpoint], shuffle=True, validation_split=0.5)
```

I'm already extracting weights for each epoch with "ModelCheckpoint", but how can I extract flatten layer output for each epoch and save them?

Answer (score 0):

doing this with sequential models is not feasible at all.
you should use functional API

```
inp = Input((5,5,1))
x = Conv2D(50, (5,5), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inp)
xflatten = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(xflatten)

main_model = Model(inp, out) # this works same as your model
flatten_model = Model(inp, xflatten) # and this only outputs the flatten layer and is not necessary to compile it because we won't train it, it just shows the output of a layer

main_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = main_model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=1, callbacks=[model_checkpoint], shuffle=True, validation_split=0.5)
```

to see the flatten layers's output:

```
flatten_model.predict(X)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Then, I really like your solution but how can I get the output epoch per epoch? (So during the training)

Comment: thanks, for that just remove the 'epoch' attribute of fit function and put this line: "history = ..." in a for loop and print model.predict output (for getting layer output) or model.evaluate (for getting loss and acc) of the flatten model per iteration. it is just like Keras's epoch and doesn't hurt anything